# MFMailComposeViewController not populating recipients in ios 5

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I'm trying to send mail to list of email array that I receive from database, when I send the recipient list gets populated in `iOS 7` but when I tried in `iOS 5` the recipient list doesn't get populated. Any Idea why? This is my mail function

```
-(void)sendEmailToContacts:(NSArray *)fList withText:(NSString *)emailText withTag:(NSInteger )tag
{
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposer.view.tag=tag;
        NSString *htmlBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@\">%@</a>",_currentAdd.contentUrl,addtext];
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:htmlBody isHTML:YES];
        [mailComposer setSubject:_currentMail.subject];
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailComposer setToRecipients:fList];
        [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email in its current state.");
    }
}
```

My `fList` (recipient list) is an `NSArray`, this is a sample output of my fList

```
(
    "john@gmail.com",
    "mary@gmail.com",
    "akhil@gmail.com",
    "tester@gmail.com"
)
```

Comment: can you put breakpointed on sendEmailToContacts method and examine if fList contains specified email list, it could be nil?

Comment: it is works for ios6 and above

Comment: i checked with breakpoint, the flist contains email as i have posted above, it works for ios7, i dont have ios6 sdk so dont know if it works for that

Comment: @Gamerlegend Check updated answer of Bhavesh Lakum i hope this time it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)sendEmailToContacts:(NSArray *)fList withText:(NSString *)emailText withTag:(NSInteger )tag
{
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        //mailComposer.view.tag=tag;
        NSString *htmlBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@\">%@</a>",_currentAdd.contentUrl,addtext];
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:htmlBody isHTML:YES];
        [mailComposer setSubject:_currentMail.subject];
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailComposer setToRecipients:fList];
        [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email in its current state.");
    }
}
```

Apparently the issue was with setting tag if I try to set the tag before setToRecipients line it will not show the recipients list in iOS 5, it will work if the setting tag line is commented out or set after setToRecipients.

Answer (score 0):

Recipients are expected as immutable array. check your array type

```
  NSArray *usersTo = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"raja@apple.com"];
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:usersTo];
```

Comment: I tried troubleshooting by manually assigning the fList as you suggested, NSArray *fList = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"raja@apple.com"]; BUT STILL I HAVE SAME ISSUE, it works on iOS7 but not on iOS5

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
        NSArray *fList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"raja@apple.com",@"john@gmail.com",@"mary@gmail.com",@"akhil@gmail.com",@"tester@gmail.com", nil];

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposer.view.tag=tag;
        NSString *htmlBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@\">%@</a>",_currentAdd.contentUrl,addtext];
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:htmlBody isHTML:YES];
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailComposer setSubject:_currentMail.subject];
        mailComposer.delegate = self;
        [mailComposer setToRecipients:fList];
        [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: what is mailComposeViewController here in mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate?

Comment: No need to write that @Gamerlegend

Comment: @Gamerlegend mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate is needed in ios 5 for cancel mail view and can you please tell what error comes ,because i tested this code its run perfect with me

Comment: I omitted that line, what is mailComposeViewController here, is it referring to my current View controller?

Comment: no it is useful to close mail sending window when you press on cancel button in ios 5

Comment: I have added mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self, in the answered code there is also mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self; I ommited that one. There is no error but the recepient list is not getting populated in iOS 5 but gets populated in iOS 6 and above, I was wondering if I have to set any other delegate for iOS 5.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45104/discussion-between-maul-and-gamerlegend)

Comment: Just add this line and test mailComposer.delegate = self i hope this time it will work. see updated answer

Comment: I am now getting a warning on mailComposer.delegate = self; assigning to id <UINavigationControllerDelegate> from incompatible type const __Strong
I have added the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, is there anything else I have to add

Comment: hello can you come in chat with simply click on link i have to discuss with you